# Hey, I have a banner of images trasitioning left on loop, but I would like to add text on hover to those images. Thankss

Tags: html, css, image, hover, css-transitions

Hello!
I have a banner of images trasitioning left on loop, and
I would like to put text when hovering the images, I can´t seem to do it. I have tried million thing and this is something for a school work that is to deliver in 3 days, so if someone could help me, i would really apreciate. 
 Thanks!!

This is how i have the pictures, i have tried putting them into divs, but it stops the transition.

```css
.slideshow {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    /* I removed these two for added clarity in snippet :: Rickard */
    /*padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 95px;*/
    width: 8100px;
    height: 380px;
    left: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#img1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.img {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
   }
    
   @keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
       margin-left: -3800px;
    }
   }
    
   @-moz-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: -3800px;
    }
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: -3800px;
    }
   }
    
   @-ms-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: -3800px;
    }
   }
    
   @-o-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: -3800px;
    }
   }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmyk.jpg" id="img1" class="img" alt="Fachada Canelada">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBDp.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5dX.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwlAe.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Fj.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmyk.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBDp.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5dX.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwlAe.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Fj.jpg" id="img1" class="img1" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Easiest way to display a text, for this occasion, is to use pseudo-elements (*::before* or *::after*). You can't use pseudo-elements on image elements, so you need to change them all into divs.
2. You want the page to be responsive, so it looks nice on different screen resolutions.
3. You want to repeat as little code as possible, and make the code easy to update in the future. Do that with CSS variables.

a. You should reserve `#id` for unique elements when it comes to styling; trying to call `#img` as you did can result in faulty display.

b. Avoid using `float` as much as you can in the design. `position: absolute` too, if possible.

c. It feels nicer IMHO to animate on `left` instead of `margin-left`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="img one"   data-tooltip="Fachada Canelada"></div>
  <div class="img two"   data-tooltip="image two"></div>
  <div class="img three" data-tooltip="image three"></div>
  <div class="img four"  data-tooltip="image four"></div>
  <div class="img five"  data-tooltip="image five"></div>
  <div class="img six"   data-tooltip="image six"></div>
  <div class="img seven" data-tooltip="image seven"></div>
  <div class="img eight" data-tooltip="image eight"></div>
  <div class="img nine"  data-tooltip="image nine"></div>
  <div class="img ten"   data-tooltip="image ten"></div>
</div>
```

I changed your HTML into the following. What's interesting at first is just how I differ between the different divs with the `class` attribute. I will explain `data-tooltip` later.

The slideshow CSS is simple:

```
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Set a width as the same of the screen (responsive!) to avoid the horizontal scrollbars your code had. Use `flex` to display all the children in `.slideshow` on the same row.

```
.slideshow > .img {
  min-width: 100%;`
  padding-left: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Give all the children a `min-width` of 100% of the parent size (which is 100% of the screen width). Use `padding` instead of `margin` because the flex property can't take margin into account when figuring out a width, but it calculates padding. In order to make the `div.img` element stay at a min-width of 100%, without the padding adding extra width, use `box-sizing` to let padding be part of the calculated width.

```
.img.one {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmyk.jpg");
}

...

.slideshow > .img {
  /* ... previous CSS code */
  background-position: 50px center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Use the images as a background, and add more properties in `div.img` to place the background element where you want it. You need to move it `50px` if you want to make room for the padding.

```
.slideshow > .img {
  position: relative;

  /* ... previous CSS code */
}

.slideshow > .img::before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip); /* displays the value of attribute data-tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* move it almost to the middle vertically */
  left: 50px; /* take into account the padding */
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* Move the element up as far as half it's own size */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0px; /* 1rem = the font size for your normal (bread) text */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* black transparent background */
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Now comes the text on the image. Use the pseudo-element `::before` (or ::after), which needs a `content` property. Use `position: absolute` to place the text wherever you want it, but don't forget to add `position: relative` to `div.img`. You need it to be relative anyway, because the animation is changed to `left: -3800px`.

`data-tooltip` could be named whatever, as long as it begins with `data-`. `data-caption` would probably be a better suited name for it. You could also use `alt`, as in `content: attr(alt)`, but that wont give another programmer any clue about the special usage for *alt* – to show it as a tooltip.

```
.slideshow > .img::before {
  display: none;
  /* ... previous CSS code */
}

.slideshow > .img:hover::before {
  display: block;
}
```

You want however the code to only be displayed while hovering, so hide the pseudo-element and then only display it when hovering `div.img`.

And now comes the repeatable part. You can solve that with CSS variables. Padding is written as `50px` on three different places. A change on any of these later on will almost certainly not be updated on all places. Add a CSS variable to `div.img`.

```
.slideshow > .img {
  --left-spacing: 50px;
  /* ... previous CSS code */
  padding-left: var(--left-spacing);
  /* ... */
  background-position: var(--left-spacing) center;
}

.slideshow > .img::before {
  /* ... previous CSS code */
  left: var(--left-spacing);
  /* ... */
}
```

... and you can also use `calc()` to make the animation responsive. Add `--slideshow-items` to `div.img` and use that variable in all your animation code:

```
@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - 1));
  }
}
```

`-1` to move the element to the left, `100vm` is the screen width, `--slideshow-items` is a CSS variable that I added to `div.img` to show the number of images, and you need to subtract `1` from it to disregard the width of the first item, otherwise you will end up with a small animation of white space.

The full code below, which you can try out:

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img.one {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmyk.jpg");
}

.img.two {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBDp.jpg");
}

.img.three {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5dX.jpg");
}

.img.four {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwlAe.jpg");
}

.img.five {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Fj.jpg");
}

.img.six {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmyk.jpg");
}

.img.seven {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBDp.jpg");
}

.img.eight {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5dX.jpg");
}

.img.nine {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwlAe.jpg");
}

.img.ten {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Fj.jpg");
}

.slideshow > .img {
  --left-spacing: 50px;
  --slideshow-items: 10;
  --ignore-width-of-first-item: 1;
  
  position: relative;
  padding-left: var(--left-spacing);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 100%;
  
  background-position: var(--left-spacing) center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  -webkit-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
     -o-animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
        animation: bannermove 25s linear infinite;
}

.slideshow > .img::before {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: var(--left-spacing);
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.slideshow > .img:hover::before {
  display: block;
}
    
@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - var(--ignore-width-of-first-item)));
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - var(--ignore-width-of-first-item)));
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - var(--ignore-width-of-first-item)));
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - var(--ignore-width-of-first-item)));
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-1 * 100vw * (var(--slideshow-items) - var(--ignore-width-of-first-item)));
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="img one"   data-tooltip="Fachada Canelada"></div>
  <div class="img two"   data-tooltip="image two"></div>
  <div class="img three" data-tooltip="image three"></div>
  <div class="img four"  data-tooltip="image four"></div>
  <div class="img five"  data-tooltip="image five"></div>
  <div class="img six"   data-tooltip="image six"></div>
  <div class="img seven" data-tooltip="image seven"></div>
  <div class="img eight" data-tooltip="image eight"></div>
  <div class="img nine"  data-tooltip="image nine"></div>
  <div class="img ten"   data-tooltip="image ten"></div>
</div>
```